# Mapear uma tabela e ativar o Auto-incremento de um campo FK no PostGre usando o EF Core e Fluent Api

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, migrations, fluent-api, entity-framework-core

Não estou conseguindo ativar o Auto_Incremento do campo ContatoTipoId no PostGre. No mapeamento da tabela eu especifiquei o recurso "ValueGeneratedOnAdd", mas quando eu atualizo o banco com o Migrations, nada muda. Quando tento inserir um registro na Aplicação dá erro, pois o campo não está sendo incrementado. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Um abraço a todos!

public class ContatoTipoMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("ContatoTipo");

```
        builder.HasKey(ct => new { ct.Id });

        builder.Property(ct => ct.Id)
             .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(ct => ct.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ContatoTipoId")
            .HasColumnType("integer")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(ct => ct.Descricao)
           .HasColumnName("Descricao")
           .HasColumnType("character varying(50)")
           .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(ct => ct.PadraoSistema)
          .HasColumnName("PadraoSistema")
          .HasColumnType("boolean");

    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu tenho casos parecidos que funcionam o auto incremento, porém nas minhas tabelas as chaves primárias são do tipo Guid (UUID).

Pesquisando sobre o seu problema o [Npgsql em Value Genaration](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/value-generation.html) pede para que habilite a opção `ForNpgsqlUseIdentityColumns()`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    => modelBuilder.ForNpgsqlUseIdentityColumns();
```

Lembrando que o PostgreSQL chama seu auto incremento de *Serial*. No link você encontra a documentação muito bem feita para todas essas questões.

Espero ter ajudado.